# How to configurate platex2e in texmaker and texlive?

Tags: texlive, texmaker, windows, platex

I'm trying to use a japanese resume template that at default settings give me this error:
[image]

According to "https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29111" i changed to platex:
[image]

but now when i try to compile it gives me the small "log file not found" windows.

What could i be doing wrong?

edit:
1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

Comment: already tried platex instead o complete route with the same result, i'll try updating texlive...

Comment: Both ptex and platex are installed, not found windows still appears.

Comment: sorry with not found message i meant the "log file not found" windows. How do i know if the pdflatex use by texmaker is the same that is in the folder of the image 2)?

Comment: I don't have windows texlive or texmaker locally so I have helped all I can, others can probably give more specific advice.

Comment: Can you run `platex <YOURFILE>` in a cmd.exe shell, and see whether it works?